# Why does my cron output file name have a \r at the end?

Tags: cron

In my cron spool I am doing:

`5 * * * * php test.php >> test.txt`

I can see that the cron is running the PHP script but the output file is called:

"test.txt\r"

why?

how can I open that file to see what's inside or how can I make cron not append that \r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you must have edited your crontab on a Windows machine.

Linux terminates its lines with `\n`. Windows does so with `\r\n`. On Linux, `\r` is just another character. Thus, your crontab probably reads:

```
5 * * * * php test.php >> test.txt\r
```

and will show you that if you open it with an editor on Linux that shows control characters.

Answer (score 3):

Try running the command `dos2unix` on your cron file. Assuming you're on a Debian/Ubuntu operating system:

```
sudo dos2unix /etc/cron.d/your_cronfile_name
```

This happens if the file was created or edited in a Windows environment. Since it has a trailing `\r` character that is usually appended by Window's text editors. As mentioned by Amadan, this `\r` character is being appended to the end of your `test.txt` string.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by @martin-konecny 's suggestion
Was facing similar issue building a docker container, made the following changes in the Docker file

RUN apt-get install -y dos2unix
RUN dos2unix /etc/cron.d/cronjob
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cronjob

PS: cronjob is the name of the cron file